# How get nested, relative includes to work?

Tags: php, phpseclib, php-include

I am using a 3rd party php library ([phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/)) that has files which include other files. It only seems to work when I have it installed in the "root" of whatever directory I'm including the first file from. If I put it in a sub-folder, the includes in the phpseclib files become unable to find the other files, despite them being relative!

This works (installed it directly in my folder):

```
include( "File/X509.php" );
```

This does *not* work (installed it in a sub-folder in my folder):

```
include( "phpseclib/File/X509.php" );
```

What fails is X509.php's call to include a file:

```
require_once('File/ASN1.php');
```

I know this occurs because once I include x509.php into my script, the code is executed there. Without changing the PHP code in the included library, is there any way to make this work? To make the include use a path relative to where I installed it?

EXAMPLE:

Assume a file structure:

```
/myfolder/myscript.php
/myfolder/sub/file/x509.php
/myfolder/sub/file/asn1.php
```

myscript.php

```
<?php include( "sub/file/x509.php" ); ?>
```

x509.php

```
<?php include( "file/asn1.php" ); ?>
```

asn1.php

```
<?php echo "included"; ?>
```

Comment: Please give the returned error, and fix the typo in `include` to avoid people complaining about it.

Comment: @BorisGuéry I fixed the typos and posted the answer below.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld why? My answer actually makes it work.

Comment: Don, ah good solution! I voted up on that one!:-)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld thanks, there's always a solution in PHP! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just need to add the path like this (and then reset it after):

```
//This is so we don't screw up anything else in the PHP web app
$currentIncludePath = get_include_path();

//Need to let phpseclib know where to find its files
set_include_path( "phpseclib" . PATH_SEPARATOR . $currentIncludePath );

//Now include the file(s)
include( "phpseclib/File/X509.php" );

//Now set back to normal
set_include_path( $currentIncludePath );
```

Comment: If in various include paths within there is a file called "model/user.php" your approach would return the first one matching an include path which may or may not be the one relative to the file that the include was issued in.

Comment: @Orangepill good point. In my case, there's no risk of this since `phpseclib` uses folder names I would never use. So, is there another solution (assuming I cannot, or do not want to, change anything in the `phpseclib` files)?

Comment: Setting the include_path is pretty much the PEAR way, which is what phpseclib's CS are based off of.

Answer (score 2):

Use the chdir to change the current working directory. I would also advise using getcwd to get the working directory before you do this then changing back to that directory when done.

```
$cwd = getcwd();
chdir("phpseclib/");
include("File/X509.php");
chdir($cwd);
```

Comment: This will not fix the problem. If file.php includes anything in a subfolder, it still will not find it (as that subfolder is not part of the include search paths). See my answer below.

Comment: if you are including a file relative to the file that you are in this method indeed does work. Nothing has to go into the include path.

Comment: except, as stated in my question, I do not want to change the files I included. So I can do this for my include of "file/x509.php" but when that file includes another relative file, it would not work.

Comment: I think your best option is then to do a chdir before and after the include. I will update the answer.

Comment: is there a reason why `chdir` would be better (or worse) than my answer below (where I do the same thing but by saving, changing and restoring the include path)?

Comment: I think they are going to be roughly equivelent. I would suggest prepending the phpseclib as opposed to appending just so that it will resolve prior to anything else already in your include path.

Comment: i.e. `set_include_path("phpseclib".PATH_SEPARATOR.$currentIncludePath);`